# How to concatenate $1 with number in a regex

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to insert the number between two patterns:

```
$s = 'id="" value="div"';
$s =~ s/(id=")(".*)/$1123$2/;
```

Of course I got the error and ***" value="div"*** as a result.
The expected result is ***id="123" value="div"***.

In the replacement I meant $1, then number 123 and then $2, but not $1123 and then $2.
What is the correct replacement in the regex? I would like to do it in one single regex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$s =~ s/(id=")(".*)/$1123$2/;  # Use of uninitialized value $1123 in concatenation (.) or string
```

Though you expected it to substitute for `$1`, perl sees it as the variable `$1123`. Perl has no way to know that you meant `$1`. So you need to limit the *variablisation* to `$1` by specifying it as `${1}`:

```
$s =~ s/(id=")(".*)/${1}123$2/;
```

It is always a good idea to include the following at the top of your scripts. They will save you a lot of time and effort.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

For example, running your script with the above modules included results in the error message:

```
Use of uninitialized value $1123 in concatenation (.) or string at /tmp/test.pl line 7.
```

(Disregard the reported script name and line numbers.) It clearly states what perl expected.

Another approach using look-behind and look-ahead assertions:

```
$s =~ s/(?<=id=")(?=")/123/;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I searched for ${1} syntax.

Comment: I prefer the look behind and ahead way

Comment: @justintime, Bonus: The version with the lookarounds is faster because it doesn't have any captures.

Comment: I was looking exactly for this. Both solutions work for perl, but for javascript/java Regex `${1}` doesn't work. Do you know how it would be for this regex flavor? I need to follow the [Java Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
$s =~ s/(id=")(".*)/$1."123".$2/e;
```

Usage example:

```
$ cat 1.pl
$s = 'id="" value="div"';
$s =~ s/(id=")(".*)/$1."123".$2/e;
print $s,"\n";

$ perl 1.pl
id="123" value="div"
```

Comment: This is a wrong variant. The result will be id="."1"." value="div"

Comment: I added example of usage. As you can see the variant is not wrong