# Concatenating a Perl regex selection

Tags: regex, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to concatenate $1 with number in a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762552/how-to-concatenate-1-with-number-in-a-regex)

I am trying to replace all instances of `SomeText` in my file with `SomeText2` using a simple regex replace from the command line (on Windows):

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/(SomeText)/$12/g" sometext.txt
```

This doesn't work because there is no `$12` selection. How can I properly indicate the `$1` selection token without a space after it?

Comment: Found [How to concatenate $1 with number in a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762552/how-to-concatenate-1-with-number-in-a-regex)

Comment: Well, just do as it says there. (And use single quotes.)

Comment: Yep, this is an exact duplicate. Whoops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`${1}`

As a general rule, inside a Regexp or interpolated string literal, you can use `{}` after any `$` or `@` sigil to explicitly delimit the name of the variable you care about.

And yes, as @Mat says, if you're on a Unix system of some kind, use single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This is, I think, most suitable for a look-around assertion, or the `\K` escape:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/SomeText\K/2/g" sometext.txt
```

Or with look-behind assertion:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/(?<=SomeText)/2/g" sometext.txt
```

This will prevent whatever is before the `\K`, or inside the look-behind, to be removed, hence you do not need to put it back.

You can also use the long syntax for variables, which is to use `${name}`, i.e. `${1}`.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, you don't need to use capture variables at all:

```
s/SomeText/SomeText2/g
```

For the answer to your more general question about variable interpolation, see Dan's answer.